# Hiding icon(s) from QGIS toolbar(s)

Tags: qgis, toolbar, icon

Is it possible to hide some icons from QGIS toolbar(s) which are not used often?

I tried with `Settings > Interface Customization` but I didn't find an option for removing a single icon, however here is possible to remove icon groups but I would like to remove individual icons.

Is there such an option(s)?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You are nearly there with interface customisation - if you hove over the icon you'll get it's name - you can then search in the interface customisation dialogue for the tool, untick it, then when you restart QGIS it will be removed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems it works actually. Many thanks